# kernel module nvidia with bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, kernel-modules, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Bumblebee is refusing to work due to unable to finding the nvidia kernel module (I think) but I do have others.

```
junke@1215N:~$ modprobe nv # tab tab :)
nvidia-current  nvidiafb        nvram           nv_tco
```

Should I just create a symlink to nvidia-current (and where?) or will this make matters worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've installed the PPA version from ppa:mj-casalogic/Bumblebee. You're possibly seeing something like:

> FATAL: Error inserting nvidia_current (.../nvidia-current.ko): No such device

This is caused by executing ACPI methods in the wrong order which messes up the PCI configuration space and thereby confusing the machine. Therefore, acpi_call has been removed from Bumblebee 3.0 since there is a better alternative for nvidia Optimus laptops.

For installation instructions of Bumblebee, see [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)

Comment: nope the nvidia-current is there and your link is 404
I did use the repos stable and bumblebee is installed

Comment: "the repos stable", did you mean `ppa:mj-casalogic/bumblebee` or `ppa:bumblebee/stable`? Could you add the output of `lspci -vvnn -d10de:` to your question (no need to run it with `sudo`)?

Comment: Had some mix up, the nvidia-current is there and I did use the caselogic repro for bumblebee, the libjpeg-turbo and virtualgl are now from stable there were not before but still the same err. lspci -> 


04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:0a76] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
 !!! Unknown header type 7f

Comment: So your card is disabled. As you can read [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/ACPI-Removed), you're recommended to remove Bumblebee from the mj-casalogic and wait until the stable version is released. You can follow us on http://twitter.com/Team_Bumblebee for news.

Comment: with the one from mj-caselogic it would just enabled give a dot and disable again. I've added the project on twitter :) Thanks for your support.

Comment: By the way, to enable your card again, you need to run `/usr/local/bin/bumblebee-disablecard` before uninstall Bumblebee. Otherwise, your card will stay disabled.

Comment: what use would I have from it without bumblebee / optirun?

Comment: The called method may not be stable. Even if your card looks down, you may experience lock ups after some time. You're basically choosing between saving power and stability.

Comment: Haven't had any lock ups with or without the card enabled :)

Comment: Updated! The stable release is now available.

Comment: I followed up your instructions and it is still not working..

junke@1215N:~$ optirun glxgears
The Bumblebee X server was not available, please check the
Bumblebee logfile at /var/log/bumblebee.log
==================================================

One log pointing to another